# Print succeeds but logging module throws exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, encoding, python-unicode

I'm trying to log the contents of a file, but I get some funny behavior from the logging module (and not only that one).

Here is the file contents:

```
"Testing …"
Testing å¨'æøöä
"Testing å¨'æøöä"
```

And here is how I open and log it:

```
with codecs.open(f, "r", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
        script = myfile.read()
        log.debug("Script type: {}".format(type(script)))
        print(script)
        log.debug("{}".format(script.encode("utf8")))
```

The line where I log the type of the object shows up as follows in my logs:

```
Script type: <type 'unicode'>
```

Then the `print ...` line prints the contents correctly to console, but, the logging module throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 882, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I remove the `.encode("utf8")` bit from that last line, I get the expected exception:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is just to demonstrate the problem. It's not only the logging module. Rest of my code also throws similar exceptions when dealing with this "unicode" string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging handles Unicode values just fine:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> script = u'"Testing …"'
>>> logging.debug(script)
DEBUG:root:"Testing …"
```

(Writing to a log file will result in UTF-8 encoded messages).

Where you went wrong is by mixing byte strings and Unicode values while using `str.format()`:

```
>>> "{}".format(script)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If you used a *`unicode`* format string you avoid the forced implicit encoding:

```
>>> u"{}".format(script)
u'"Testing \u2026"'
```

Comment: Oh! Mixing unicode with ASCII... I'm banging my head to wall right now (and typing at the same time). Thanks a lot. This must be one of those days... I'll mark it as the answer.